# Semantic Tagging and analysis or extraction of text (Windows/OS X)

Tags: data-analysis, text-processing

I'm looking for a software to add semantic tags to a long, structured text, with the ability to search for, extract, maybe analyse these tags.

Specifically, the text is structured into chapters and subchapters. Within these are descriptions of specific requirements and implementation guidelines. The chapter structure is important and needs to be available in all extractions/analysis (e.g. I need to know in which chapter a tag is).

I want to mark these requirements, guidelines, etc. and be able to extract them, e.g. "show me all requirements of type X".

I would like to have this in a standalone-software, to be installed on consultant notebooks. The notebooks are all Windows machines, but if it runs on OS X as well it would make development much easier.

My end purpose is to match the requirements to a specific installation as a checklist / audit. If the tool can do something like that as well, fantastic. If not, I'm happy with extracting the data and creating the checklist seperately from it. I would want to have the ability to link to the full text while compiling the checklist, in case any detailled questions arise ("ok, are we compliant? What exactly does it say?").

I think I would be able to build something like this in SMW, the semantic software I know best, but I would prefer a standalone solution that doesn't require a local webserver. So a standalone-software similar to SMW might also serve my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to build something like this using [python](http://www.python.org/) and the natural language tool kit - [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/) *[Auto-tagify](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/auto_tagify/) might be a good starting point.*

Python and NLTK are both free, gratis & open source, allowed to be used commercially and are cross platform running on just about anything. If you decided to have a web server python can start a light weight one with a single command line or has numerous frameworks or there are a number of GUI frameworks available.

Answer (score 0):

Well I believe you need an xml editor (like a database manager). Here's what I've found: [Oxygen XML Editor](https://www.oxygenxml.com/)

[image: XML Editor screenshot]

---

[image: Profiling condition sets screenshot]

[image: Edit profiling attributes screenshot]

[image: Output screenshot]

[Source page](https://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_editor/wysiwyg_xml_editor_profiling_conditional_text.html)

**EDIT:** Of course you need to make structure one by one. I don't know if this can be automated if you have too long text.

You could search for **xml editor** or **list of xml editors** for alternatives.